# How to create multiple notification for each uploading progress in foreground service?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Here I tried to implement feature ,user to user send media
I tried to upload media using foreground service.
I want to set multiple notification in foreground service like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zxc4.jpg)

what I have used

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                        CHANNEL_ID,
                        "Example Service Channel",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                );
                NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
            }
    }
```

service class

```
public class Upload extends Service
{
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("sending to "+firstName)
                .setProgress(100,0,true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_la)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(unique_id, notification);
}
}
```

from activity
On each time of new uploading

```
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, Upload.class);
                        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
```

this is show only single notification

Comment: Is your `unique_id`  different each other notifications?

Comment: yes it is different each time